# Почему SurfaceView создался несколько раз и динамически меняется?

Tags: android, android-canvas

Попробую сформулировать нормально вопрос. У меня есть простое приложение, но для этого вопроса я еще больше все упростил, чтобы сосредоточиться на корне проблемы. Суть приложения - есть часть экрана, в моем случае это `SurfaceView`, где динамически после каждого нажатия кнопки должна появляться геометрическая фигура и с каждым нажатием их должно быть все больше. Это я сделал, но у меня появилась проблема. Я уже обрезал максимально все, что мог в функционале, чтобы понять, где баг и все равно не понимаю почему у меня создается три таких `SurfaceView` (и мне тем более не ясно почему именно три), которые по очереди после нажатия кнопки меняются, хотя у меня должен быть только один `SurfaceView`. Это приводит к тому, что у меня появляется три разных набора фигур, которые по очереди заполняются, вместо одного. 
Первый `SurfaceView` создается зеленого цвета: `mCanvas.drawColor(Color.GREEN);`. Дальше, не знаю почему, после нажатия кнопки создается как понимаю другой `SurfaceView` и экран становится черным. После нового нажатия тоже самое (третий `SurfaceView`), на четвертое нажатия опять возвращается к зеленому и опять по циклу. Я прекрасно понимаю, что проблема в двух строчках в слушателе для кнопки (обозначил комментарием), но я никак не могу понять в чем ошибка...

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        hideActionBar();
        initView();

        mSurfaceView.getHolder().addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {

            @Override
            public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
                mCanvas = null;
                mSurfaceHolder = null;
                mSurfaceHolder = mSurfaceView.getHolder();
                mCanvas = mSurfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
                mCanvas.drawColor(Color.GREEN);
                mSurfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(mCanvas);
            }

            @Override
            public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            }

            @Override
            public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
            }
        });

        mRectangleButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // Проблема тут!
                mCanvas = mSurfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
                // drawRectangle();
                mSurfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(mCanvas);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я разобрался в проблеме. Суть в том, что `SurfaceView` использует множественные буферы. Именно те два черных экрана и были теми буферами. Для того, чтобы избежать этой проблемы нужно использовать один трюк с `Bitmap`. Вот как выглядит код обновленного слушателя для кнопки (тут есть еще дописанные строчки кода для реализации этого слушателя - они не обязательны, но я оставил их для лучшего понимания).

```
    mRectangleButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (mScreenBitmap == null) return;  
            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(mScreenBitmap);
            if (mShapeFactory == null)
                mShapeFactory = new ShapeFactory(getApplicationContext());
            Shape shape = mShapeFactory.getShape(getApplicationContext(), "rectangle");
            mVector.add(shape);
            shape.draw(canvas);
            canvas = mSurfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);
            canvas.drawBitmap(mScreenBitmap, 0, 0, null); 
            mSurfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
            mRectangleCount++;
            Log.d(TAG, "Rectangle:" + mRectangleCount);
            updateShapeCount();
        }
    });
```

Для более детального ознакомления стоит почитать теоретический ответ на [этот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30832960/draw-objects-trails-on-a-surfaceview) вопрос, а пример кода для решения проблемы я брал из ответа на [этот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36266994/how-to-draw-to-canvas-from-surfaceview) вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

Размести внутри

> `surfaceCreated() surfaceDestroyed() surfaceChanged()`

```
Log.E("surfaceCreated", "OK")
```

И посмотри Логи после нажатия кнопки; Так мы узнаем вызываются ли эти методы после `mSurfaceHolder.lockCanvas();`

Comment: Ну эти методы не зависят от кнопок. Первый метод вызывается при запуске Activity, второй сразу же тоже, а третий во время закрытия. Я частично понял в чем моя проблема. Это буферизация View компонентов и там как раз есть два буффера. Я немного смог поправить код основываясь на этом ответе:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36266994/how-to-draw-to-canvas-from-surfaceview

Но все равно, черный экран появляется, хотя уже все фигуры на общем полотне.